# How to find a relation between given numbers to get a given result?

Tags: arithmetic

I have

```
f(2, 3, 6)  =  5/6;
f(4, 3, 12) = 17/6;
f(3, 3, 9)  = 11/6;
f(2, 0, 2)  =  2;
```

How can I find the relation f for the given values?

Comment: $f(a, b, c)=a+2-\frac{1}{b!}-\frac{c}{a}$ seems to work, but so do some other things. Are there any other conditions on $f$?

Comment: I just know that f:N->R+ and the given values. Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately, with enough imagination there are infinite functions through these points.

Comment: I know. All I have is some values, integer numbers, and the results that can be real positive numbers. The numbers can change position and the result will still be the same. I have to create a program that will magically give the right result for other values. I do not need a real function just a relation between numbers that i can then code. Thanks Apple For suggestion, the function works fine for non 0 b.

Comment: @Mirceac21 can use multivariate Lagrange interpolation? https://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol1issue1/S01002.pdf